# C++ static data field objects

Tags: c++, object, struct

i have this line of code that I cant seem to understand

```
 long TNode :: occupancy = 0;
```

As you can see, it is a Tnode object called occupancy?

TNode is struct in my file, and i need to increment occupancy as it is used to keep track the amount of Nodes inserted into my tree

I tried doing TNode -> occupancy++; but its giving me not declared in this scope error

If my perception is wrong, please correct my confusion

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is allocating storage for a static variable `TNode::occupancy` (i.e. static variable in the TNode class).

It is of type long.

It can be incremented by `Tnode::occupancy++`